# Подгружаю контент через load() и раскидываю данные объекта в этот контент

Tags: jquery

Подгружаю с помощью load() div со страницы param.html в контейнер на index.html.
Потом раскидываю из объекта данные в подгруженный div, вот тут и возникает проблема, данные появляются на миг и снова возвращаются к дефолтным значениям, вероятно проблема в методе load()? Подскажите как выйти из этой ситуации?

```js
(($) => {
    'use strict';
    let $itemData = $('#indexLayoutGrid1 .col-2'),
      cartData;
    let myObj = {};
  };

  let actions = {
    init: () => {},

    changeDelivery: function(that) {
      $itemData.load('param.html #paramLayoutGrid' + changeNumIndex);
      actions.castInput(changeNumIndex);
    },
    castInput: function(changeNumIndex) {
      cartData = actions.getStorage() || myObj;
    }
  };

  $.func = function() {
    actions.changeDelivery(this);
  };
})(jQuery);

$(() => {
  'use strict';
  $('#menu').find("[id^='wb_indexHeading']").click($.func).first().click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.func = function() {
    actions.changeDelivery(this);
    return false;
  };
```

Comment: пробовал через return false; не работает, все так же. Видимо через ajax придется.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, вроде работает

```
$itemData.load('param.html #paramLayoutGrid'+changeNumIndex,() =>
actions.castInput(changeNumIndex));
```